# JMS - Asynchronous Processing - Dealing with Parent / Child processes Dependencies

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, architecture, message-queue

**Issue:**   I have a single process request start that breaks up into multiple levels of queues / MDBs to speed up processing through parallelism.  The question is, what is the best way to know when each level of processing is complete to do a close out process? Keep in mind I am dealing with high volumes of messages so performance has to be taken into consideration.

**Technology Stack:**

- EJB 3.0 MDB's
- Hibernate 4.2.11 ()
- Spring 4.0.1
- Websphere MQ's
- Oracle 11g database.

**Solution 1 Attempted**: Parent process polls sub process until its complete at each sub-level. This means an open MDB session that will consistently poll a response queue for messages at each level for it's sub process to complete.

**Advantage:** You avoid calls constantly to the database to determine, "Am I done yet" .

**Disadvantage:**

- This solution maintains consistent open input connections to MQ while it waits and polls for the process to complete. Number of connections go up as you scale.
- If any messages are lost, it will throw off the count of the polling mechanism. Not very reliable.
- If you have persistence turned on ( which you should most times ) it will re-process the initial request since it will still be open, re-doing the entire request.

**Solution 2 Proposal:**

- Instead of using polling mechanism, use more MDB's binded to response queues at each level of processing. Have everything work in isolation.

How to determine if the process is complete? As each message comes to response MDB , it can check the database status table to determine if its complete.

**Advantage:**

- List item
- All messages work in isolation.
- Better suited for supporting high availability and persistent messages.
- Prevents any long running open processes against the MQ.

**Disadvantage:** This could mean many calls to the database for determining completeness. I think this would be a major scalability issue as the number of messages go up.

I haven't used Spring batch and Spring Integration a lot but maybe that is where I should be looking for solution. Hoping someone with a lot of experience in message flow's with MDB's and MQ can give me some direction in terms of scaling / determining when a process is complete.

Answer (score 0):

A different solution would be to use the JMS bus for the children to notify the parent process when their sub task is complete. The architecture would look like this.

- Parent has a list of child tasks (with ids) that need to be completed.
- A new topic in the MQ where the child can post completion status.
- A new MDB that is bound to the completion status topic that updates the parent (for e.g. remove the completed tasks from the list).
- When the completion status for all the sub tasks is received, the parent is done.

This way, there is no additional load due to polling on the children (solution 1) or the database (solution 2).

This would also allow you to extend the architecture to introduce more sophisticated control mechanisms. For e.g. you can monitor the progress of the tasks / make sure none of them crashed by posting periodic progress messages from children to the status topic.

Comment: I think the JMS Bus  is a definite scalability must. Just to address tcp/ip connections limitations of MQ. The only catch would be I would require set-up of a topic per sub-level of processings. Also how to address the same problem of knowing...when is the process actually complete? The mdb wouldn't know the last message. I suppose I could add header information so it can track the number of messages it completes as if it were polling. However I think the same issue of a "lost message" scenario breaking the process might occur. But it does address some issues and is a valid option.

Comment: The lost message issue has to be handled for the forward path anyway. The same solution can be used for this purpose as well. Also, this need not be only for the "Task completed" message. You can use the JMS bus for "Sign of life" messages from the sub-tasks to know if they are alive or not.

Comment: I wanted to give this some time for people to look at my question. However I think the best solution involves using a decentralized manager for the process. Like Spring Integration or Camel. This allows for a continuous process working in isolation but allows you to allow custom execution based on the overall process. Like wire taps, counters, and status.